# why does apply only take one param in this case?

Tags: javascript, this, var, apply

I'm studying [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) and I am trying to understand why the code I am studying only passes one parameter to apply.

I first define Quo:

```
var Quo = function(string) {
  this.status = string;
};
```

Next I define get_status:

```
Quo.prototype.get_status = function() {
  return this.status;
};
```

I define statusObject:

```
var statusObject = {
  status: 'yo!'
};
```

And this is where I am lost:

```
var status = Quo.prototype.get_status.apply(statusObject);
// status is 'yo!'
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/Apply) "Apply Calls a function with a given this value and arguments provided as an array." You can see in the case, using apply I pass only a single parameter, which I believe is defining "this". Can you clear up what exactly is happening in this method, why apply is necessary, and why in this case I can only pass one param to the method, when it states two are needed. Thank you.

Comment: There are no parameters necessary for the `get_status` function, so no parameters need to be provided. If they were provided, they'd just be ignored anyway. The code could use `call` just as easily.

Comment: `.apply` isn't necessary, `.call` would have done the same thing. `.apply` is the only way to pass unknown amount of arguments to a function which you don't need here. What is the problem? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`apply` sets the context of the function being applied to the object provided in the first parameter.

```
var o;
function baz(a, b, c) {
  //do stuff
}

o = {
  foo: 'bar'
};

baz.apply(o);
//this is o
//a is undefined
//b is undefined
//c is undefined
```

If an array is passed as the second parameter, the parameters will be set based off the values in the array:

```
baz.apply(o, [1,2,3]);

//this is o
//a is 1
//b is 2
//c is 3
```

The second parameter in `apply` is optional, however `call` is typically used for settings context:

```
//these do the same thing
baz.call(o);
baz.apply(o);

//this is how they're different
baz.call(o, 1, 2, 3);
baz.apply(o, [1, 2, 3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't state that two are needed:

```
fun.apply(thisArg[, argsArray])
```

notice how `argsArray` is in brackets, it is optional.

What is happening on your call, is that your `statusObject` is passed as the `this` argument to your `get_status` function.

This means that when `get_status` executes and does `return this.status` it is in essence returning `statusObject.status`.

Apply is useful for many reasons, one of which is to invoke methods dynamically. I can pass the string name of a method in the object to be invoked like so:

```
methods = {
    init: function(message) {
        alert(message);
    }
};
function executeFunc(method) {
    methods[method].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}

//now I can call like this:
executeFunc('init', 'Hey there, this is a message');
```

An example of this can be found in my jQuery Plugin skeleton on [GitHub](https://github.com/englercj/jQuery-Plugin-Skeleton/blob/master/jquery.plugin.js#L42)

Answer (score 0):

`apply` takes one argument, the object to use as `this`, followed by the arguments *if any*.

If the function takes no arguments, e.g. you have `function f() { ... }`, you don't need to pass any arguments, so you can call `f.apply(someObject);`.

Comment: Its JavaScript, you don't *have* to pass arguments. As long as you are willing to accept the consequences of not passing them :)